# Deserialize json utc date from jira api to .net datetime

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime, jira

Jira is responding to a GET Request with this date time format:

"2013-09-17T12:07:36.000-0500"

I've gotten this far:
settings.DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff");

- 1). Will I need to escape the 'T'? (\T)
- 2). I don't know what to do for the '-0500'

  - a) It looks like zzz might work but that gets me '-05:00'
  - b) I've tried this and it didnt work: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"

Comment: I don't think jira returns a string in this form. It should either be an xml or json. Doesn't your serializer convert it to DateTime automatically?

Comment: Jira's DateTimes look like this in the response of a REST API call.

created: "2013-09-17T12:07:35.000-0500"

This is JSON we're talking about and yes I'm using a Deserializer to convert it.  The thing is the deserializer is expecting dates that are something that looks like this '\/(date)\/'

Comment: Is it possible that you see it that way. Maybe a correct serializer can give you a `DateTime`. how about posting your code and what Jira returns.

Comment: I send a GET request to search Issues and it returns raw JSON with dates formatted the way I've described.  Navigate here if you want an example: https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9.json

Comment: Which serializer do you use. Json.Net, for ex, can parse it.

Comment: I answered down there but I was trying to use DataContractJsonSerializer, I knew that would bite me!

Comment: DCJS is flawed in many areas. Even MS has switch to JSON.Net.  But if you're actually wanting to keep all the information you are given, then you should use a `DateTimeOffset` type, not a `DateTime` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). (**X** would be: *how can I process this json response*)

See how it can be done easily with [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string json = wc.DownloadString("https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9.json");
dynamic jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
DateTime dt = (DateTime)jObj.fields.updated;
```

Of course, deserializing the json string to concrete classes is also possible. In that case you  can use [this site](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: I guess this is what I get for trying to use the DataContractJsonSerializer.  Was trying not to use code outside the framework.  I've learned my lesson.  I've gotten it to work with JSON.Net and it works out of the box no DateTime formatting hell. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this snippet solves your issue?

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var json = @"{ date : ""2013-09-17T12:07:36.000-0500""}";
var date = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, DateTime>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFK"